# video is not fetching completly,

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, html5-video

I want to fetch video from mongodb than it should play that video up to video size, but its playing only some second, i gave maxUploadSize is 20mb and maxInMemorySize also 20mb,but on the jsp page, its fetching only 1mb video even video size more than 1mb.
I am not getting what to do, video should play full according to video size

here is Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome-video-controller/{videoObj}", produces = "video/webm")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getVideoForLoginPage(@PathVariable String videoObj, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

    LOG.info("Entry :: getVideoForPost");
    BufferedImage bufferedVideoForPost = null;
    URL resourcePath = null;
    byte[] videoArray = null;
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = null;
    LOG.info("videoObj-->" + videoObj);
    File videoFromMongo = new File(VIDEO_FROM_PATH + videoObj);
    GridFSDBFile videoFile = MongoUtility.getVideoFileFromMongo(videoObj);
    videoFile.writeTo(videoFromMongo);
    bufferedVideoForPost = ImageIO.read(videoFromMongo);
    videoFile.getInputStream();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentLength((int) videoFile.getLength());
    videoArray = new byte[(int) videoFile.getLength()];
    result = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(videoArray, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    videoFile.getInputStream().read(videoArray);
    LOG.info("videoArray-->" + videoArray);
    LOG.info("videoArray size-->" + videoArray.length);
    return result;
}
```

and this is html codding

```
<c:set value="${videoPostDetail.videoNames}" var="videoObj" />
<c:if test="${videoObj ne ''}">
    <video width="96%" height="220" controls id="sideVideo">
          <source src='/SocialNetworkingApp/welcome-video-controller/${videoObj}.do' type='video/webm'>

    </video>
</c:if>
```

it should play complete video,i tried lot but nothing is working, plz tell  what's problem,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution, actually problem was the chunk size, i dint set chunk size of file and by default chunkSize was less than 1 mb, 
now i added this line into the code  gfsFile.setChunkSize(uploadVideoFile.length()); and its working fine.

```
    public static void saveVideoIntoMongo(File uploadVideoFile, String videoFilePath, String newVideoFileName)
        throws IOException {

    LOG.info("Entry :: saveVideoIntoMongo");
    LOG.info("videoFilePath-->" + videoFilePath);
    LOG.info("newVideoFileName-->" + newVideoFileName);
    LOG.info("uploadVideoFile-->" + uploadVideoFile);

    DB db = getMongoDBInstance("videoDb");// later on take it from the properties file instead of hardcoding
    GridFS gfsPhoto = getGridFSForFiles(db, "video");

    if (!("").equals(newVideoFileName)) {
        GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(uploadVideoFile);
        gfsFile.setChunkSize(uploadVideoFile.length());//setting chunkSize
        gfsFile.setFilename(newVideoFileName);
        gfsFile.save();

    }

    LOG.info("Exit :: saveVideoIntoMongo");
}
```